# Make a commandline tool from C program

Tags: c, makefile, command-line-tool

If I want to make a commandline tool using makefile for, say this C program:

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

I have no previous experience with makefile or linux shell commands whatsoever. Just starting out. Can anyone tell me how to go about it?

Comment: I recommend Googling some C and Makefile tutorials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need a makefile for a single source file like this - just compile it like this:

```
$ gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo
```

If you really want a makefile though then you can do something like this:

```
#
# makefile
#

foo: foo.c
    gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo
```

then from the command line you could say:

```
$ make foo
```

or even just

```
$ make
```

Comment: You can replace `gcc` by `clang` if you use clang. For the Makefile, I'd at least use `CC = <compiler here>` and `$(CC) -Wall foo.c -o foo`, so you can easily switch compilers if you have multiple targets. Example [here](http://pastebin.com/7saKiRSd).

Comment: Yes, you can use `$(CC)` to make it completely compiler-agnostic, and also use `$(CFLAGS)` etc. I was aiming for simplicity since this is a noob question.

Comment: I agree, but I think it's good practice to learn something about macros early. :)

Comment: I take the syntax used is:

    <filename>: <filename>.c
        gcc -Wall <filename>.c -o <output_filename>

What does the "-Wall" do?

Comment: @Ashwini `-Wall` is a compiler flag (which works at least for GCC and clang) that will turn on all warnings. If you don't use this, the compiler may not show some warnings. By the way, make sure that you use **tabs** to indent in the Makefiles as some Make implementations don't like space indentation.

Comment: in simple noob language, what exactly does makefile(or "make" <what's the difference between the two> ) do?

Comment: @Ashwani: typing `make` launches the program Make. The program Make reads the makefile, which is just a text file in a syntax Make understands, and which tells Make what to do. This makefile tells Make how to compile your C code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Unix box handy, but ISTR that make(1) has some default rules that should allow you to simply type `make hello` and it will find hello.c and generate a binary named 'hello'.  Of course, for anything more complicated, you'll want to read up on make(1) or its descendents, `man make` is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Makefile:

```
hello: hello.c
    gcc -Wall -o hello hello.c


$ make hello
$ ./hello
```

You might benefit from [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Also, your program is missing a newline. You probably wanted to print `"Hello World!\n"`.

Comment: or `puts("Hello World!");` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$cat makefile
main:main.c
    gcc -o main main.c

clean:
    rm main
```